# Standardizing a column in an SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column in my SQL table named 'Dates', in which the dates are stored in different formats, like:
25/5/2000,
1st June 2013,
5/1/1996,
Jan 23,1990 etc.

I want to convert all these dates to a single format e.g. DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY. How can I do so?

Comment: What is the datatype for your 'Dates' column? I'm guessing it's varchar(). How do you know what format any of the dates are in?

Comment: I agree with the others - the type should be datetime.  I tried running something like `UPDATE Dates SET stringdates = CONVERT(varchar, CAST(stringdates as datetime), 101)` and it fails trying to handle all the different types of dates

Comment: There is a simple way to convert char to datetime, but no way to identify which format you have there in each row.

Comment: Do *you* know what date `5/1/1996` is meant to represent? Is that a day in January or May?

Comment: The datatype for my 'Dates' column is varchar. Basically, I'm developing an ETL application, where I'm extracting data from disparate sources, which may have tables containing dates in different formats. I want all the dates in one format...

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE datatype as storage type, and leave formating to the front end.

Comment: DATE datatype is only a valid type since sql 2008 (i.e. 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012). It may only be possible to use DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME if the version of SQL Server is not able to use DATE

Comment: Sure, but 2005 was nine yrs and four versions back (2014, 2012, 2008r2, 2008), and the question wasn't tagged as 2005, was it? :) Also, DATE seems more appropriate for the existing values than DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
create table Table(DateColumn varchar(20))

insert into Table values ('25/5/2000'), ('25052000'), ('5/1/1996'),('jan-23-1990'),(05012000)

select
  case len(DateColumn)
    when 10 then convert(date, DateColumn, 103)
    when 8 then convert(date, stuff(stuff(DateColumn, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'), 103)
    when 6 then convert(date, stuff(stuff(DateColumn, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'), 3)
    when 11 then convert(date,Datecolumn,103)
-- depending on string length you may query this   
end
from table
```

Comment: This is giving me the following error: "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to Convert date in you column, use this example site to understand what are you trying to accomplish, hope this helps thanks. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql